# Hello, I"m unable to get my viewpage on my polls projecr

Tags: django

I'm unable to open my view page in django for my project polls.
The URL is launched, but it is not opening and showing an error page as attached below.
The link to URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Could anyone help me to rectify the error?

Thank you.

Comment: That will be the address to your local machine for your machine (see https://www.howtogeek.com/126304/why-is-the-localhost-ip-127.0.0.1/ ), no one will be able to see the error. Please post text or a screenshot of what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Sir the link 127.0.0.1 is your computer server we can't see the errors on the page. Also you can try looking if you have started the server with **python manage.py runserver** aswell